# Randomly coloring with script doesn't work correctly

Tags: python, scripting

Consider:

[image]

I'm having trouble with making each of these circles to have a random color
and the problem is that the color is random, but that color applies to all of them.

```py
import bpy
import random as r
import math as m
n=25

for i in range(1,n+1):

    material_i= bpy.data.materials.new(f'm{i}')
    material_i.diffuse_color=(r.uniform(0,1),r.uniform(0,1),r.uniform(0,1),1)
    bpy.context.object.data.materials.append(material_i)
    angle = ((i-1)*4*(m.pi))/n
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'}, TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value":(0, 0, 0), "orient_type":'GLOBAL', "orient_matrix":((0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 0)), "orient_matrix_type":'GLOBAL', "constraint_axis":(False, False, False), "mirror":False, "use_proportional_edit":False, "proportional_edit_falloff":'SMOOTH', "proportional_size":1, "use_proportional_connected":False, "use_proportional_projected":False, "snap":False, "snap_target":'CLOSEST', "snap_point":(0, 0, 0), "snap_align":False, "snap_normal":(0, 0, 0), "gpencil_strokes":False, "cursor_transform":False, "texture_space":False, "remove_on_cancel":False, "release_confirm":False, "use_accurate":False, "use_automerge_and_split":False})
    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[2] = angle
```

Comment: Please post code as code block. Easier to see, able to copy paste to test, wont be cutoff at edge of screen capture, etc...

Comment: @Ratt Here you are! you have to make an object , select it ,then run the script.  in this case i have used a circle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part of the issue is that when you append the new material to the duplicated object you never change the index of the active material slot which remains at 0 from the initial object. If you inspect the material slots of each object in turn you continue to add another material but never assign it. I would think that instead of constantly adding additional materials you would rather just have 1 material per object in this case.

```
import bpy
import random as r
import math as m
n=25

for i in range(1,n+1):
    ob = bpy.context.object
    material_i= bpy.data.materials.new(f'm{i}')
    material_i.diffuse_color=(r.uniform(0,1),r.uniform(0,1),r.uniform(0,1),1)
    if not ob.material_slots:
        bpy.ops.object.material_slot_add()
        new_mat = material_i
        ob.material_slots[0].material = new_mat
    else:
        new_mat = material_i
        ob.material_slots[0].material = new_mat
    angle = ((i-1)*4*(m.pi))/n
    bpy.ops.object.duplicate_move(OBJECT_OT_duplicate={"linked":False, "mode":'TRANSLATION'})
    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[2] = angle
```

Comment: thank you so much!

Answer (score 5):

**Matrices, object copies  and Object Color.**

[Same Material with different key frames](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185290/same-material-with-different-key-frames)

[Why does editing a material on one object change lots of other object's materials as well?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185371/why-does-editing-a-material-on-one-object-change-lots-of-other-objects-material)

First going to give the context object the simplest of materials, that uses the object color.

[image]

All our linked copies will have the same material, and take on the value assigned to their respective object color.

**Matrices.**

For my circle have started with a skinny torus at global origin (the default)

To do what is akin to an edit mode transform of 2 in x direction will make a translation matrix and apply it the torus, which will have the effect of shifting the mesh 2 to the right while its origin remains at the center.

Next will make a rotation matrix that rotates $4 \pi / n$ radians about the z axis.

Each copy will have this rotation applied.

```
import bpy
from random import uniform
from mathutils import Matrix
from math import pi
n=25

T = Matrix.Translation((2, 0, 0))
R = Matrix.Rotation(4 * pi / n, 4, 'Z')
#M = R @ T

ob = bpy.context.object
ob.data.transform(T) # like an edit mode transform

coll = bpy.context.collection

for i in range(1, n+1):
    copy = ob.copy() # copy object
    copy.color = (uniform(0, 1), uniform(0, 1), uniform(0, 1), 1)
    copy.matrix_world @= R
    coll.objects.link(copy) # link to context collection
    ob = copy
```

[image]
*Test Run on my torus*

Comment: your approach was a little different but thanks a lot!