# how to change the color of single object separately

Tags: color

I tried to change the color of a selected sphere.But for some reason when I select it and change the color, the other spheres change the color. How can I change the color of the chosen sphere only?

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/185371/why-does-editing-a-material-on-one-object-change-lots-of-other-objects-material/185428#185428

Answer (score 0):

That's because all those speheres probably share the same material.
If you go to the material and click on the number, then it will make a copy of the material and assign it to the object, thus seperating it from all the other objects.
[image]